# TYPO3 - tx_news: include filtered list view on record page via typoscript

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

On detail view of a tx_news record I loop over the selected categories and if a record has a certain category (in this case with uid=5) load a filtered list view (related records) with the defined uid. It works also if multiple categories are selected, yet only if the additional categories selected have a higher 'sorting' value. What am I missing? That's my setup:

News/Detail.html

```
...

<!-- check category -->         
<f:if condition="{newsItem.categories}">
    <f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category">
        <f:if condition="{category.uid} == 5">
            <f:then>                

                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.newsslider" />                         

            </f:then>            
        </f:if>
    </f:for>                
</f:if>

...
```

Typoscript:

```
lib.newsslider = USER
lib.newsslider {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = News
  pluginName = Pi1
  vendorName = GeorgRinger

  switchableControllerActions {
        News {
          1 = list
        }
  }

  settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
  settings {
        categories = 5
        categoryConjunction = and
        includeSubCategories =1
        limit = 30
        detailPid = 97
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        startingpoint = 96
        templateLayout = 4
        hidePagination = 1
        list{  
          paginate {
            itemsPerPage = 9
            insertAbove = 
          }  
       }         
  }
}
```

If the additional categories selected have a lower 'sorting' value ...  e.g. like this:

```
categories => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyObjectStorageprototypeobject (2 items)
  00000000443eb767000000007f371fa2 => GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\Categoryprototypepersistent entity (uid=19, pid=1)
     sorting => protected 8 (integer)
     title => protected 'Corporates' (10 chars)
     uid => protected 19 (integer)

  00000000443eb763000000007f371fa2 => GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\Categoryprototypepersistent entity (uid=5, pid=56)
     sorting => protected 16 (integer)
     title => protected 'Press Releases' (14 chars)
     uid => protected 5 (integer)
```

I can't access the record detail page (loading forever) when I want to access a record coming from the main [17] Media & Press list view ... and after a while I get this error:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM `sys_template` WHERE (`pid` = ?) AND ((`sys_template`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`sys_template`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`sys_template`.`starttime` <= 1509472200) AND ((`sys_template`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`sys_template`.`endtime` > 1509472200))) ORDER BY `root` DESC, `sorting` ASC LIMIT 1' with params [1]: PHP Warning: mysqli::prepare(): MySQL server has gone away in /is/htdocs/path/www/typo3_src-8.7.8/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php line 92
```

TYPO3 8.7.8 & tx_news 6.1.1

Edit:

... where pageID [97] is also the detail page of the main news list view: [17] Media & Press:

```
[17] Media & Press
|_[97] News Articles
|_[96] News Archive
```

... with configuration for:

```
[17] Media & Press
- What to display: List View (without overloading Detail view)
- Starting Point: Media & Press (sys) [96]
- Category Selection: Press Releases, Weekly Update
- Category Mode: Show items with selected categories (OR)
- PageId for single news display: News Articles [97]
- PageId for list display: Media & Press [17]

[97] News Articles
- What to display: Detail View
- PageId to return to: [17] Media & Press
```

Comment: The problem is imo more about the detail pid thanh the rest? Is there something special configured or special checks there or is this page used by all news plugins

Comment: Yes ... pageID [97] is also the detail page of the main news list view: [17] Media & Press. I added more info above ... . To be more precise ... the error appears when accessing a record coming from the main [17] Media & Press list view. ... so its not the detailPid of the lib.newsslider ... I created a new detailPid=103 ... and still get can't access the record

Comment: I think the fluid category check is causing the error: <f:if condition="{category.uid} == 5"> . When I paste <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.newsslider" /> outside it's working fine also if there is a category with a lower 'sorting' value defined.